# is it possible to run an android or ios service when your mobile app is off?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

i have been working for a week to get a service to work in the background after boot on a Xamarin.Forms Android project.

i have used:

- broadcast receivers
- services
- alarms

i have set permissions galore in the manifest.
i have set filters for receivers to accept BOOT_COMPLETED

is this a permissions thing that just can't be done?

Comment: What is you problem when you implement your function ?

Comment: I ended up creating a foreground service and it's all working. other services just don't cooperate with security.